# How to Check if Trainable Weights of Keras Model Change Before/After Custom Training Loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, custom-training

I am trying to verify whether a custom training loop changes the Keras Model's weights. My current method is to `deepcopy` the `model.trainable_weights` list before training and then compare that to `model.trainable_weights` after training. Is this a valid way to make this comparison? The results of my method indicate that the weights do in fact change (which is the expected result anyway since the loss clearly decreases per epoch), but I just want to verify that what I am doing is valid. Below is code from the slightly adapted [Keras custom training loop tutorial](https://keras.io/guides/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch/) plus the code I use to compare changes in weights before/after model training:

```
# Imports
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy

# The model
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(784,), name="digits")
x1 = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(inputs)
x2 = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(x1)
outputs = layers.Dense(10, name="predictions")(x2)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

##########################
# WEIGHTS BEFORE TRAINING
##########################
# I use deepcopy here to avoid mutating the weights list during training
weights_before_training = deepcopy(model.trainable_weights)

##########################
# Keras Tutorial
##########################

# Load data
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (-1, 784))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (-1, 784))

# Reduce the size of the data to speed up training
x_train = x_train[:128] 
x_test = x_test[:128]
y_train = y_train[:128]
y_test = y_test[:128]

# Make tf dataset
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=64).batch(16)

# The training loop
print('Begin Training')
optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-3)
loss_fn = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
epochs = 2
for epoch in range(epochs):
    # Logging start of epoch
    print("\nStart of epoch %d" % (epoch,))

    # Save loss values for logging
    loss_values = []

    # Iterate over the batches of the dataset.
    for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_dataset):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            logits = model(x_batch_train, training=True)  # Logits for this minibatch
            loss_value = loss_fn(y_batch_train, logits)

        # Append to list for logging
        loss_values.append(loss_value)

        grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)

        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))

    print('Epoch Loss:', np.mean(loss_values))

print('End Training')
##########################
# WEIGHTS AFTER TRAINING
##########################

weights_after_training = model.trainable_weights

# Note: `trainable_weights` is a list of kernel and bias tensors.
print()
print('Begin Trainable Weights Comparison')
for i in range(len(weights_before_training)):
    print(f'Trainable Tensors for Element {i + 1} of List Are Equal:', tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(weights_before_training[i], weights_after_training[i])).numpy())
print('End Trainable Weights Comparison')

>>> Begin Training
>>> Start of epoch 0
>>> Epoch Loss: 44.66055
>>> 
>>> Start of epoch 1
>>> Epoch Loss: 5.306543
>>> End Training
>>>
>>> Begin Trainable Weights Comparison
>>> Trainable Tensors for Element 1 of List Are Equal : False
>>> Trainable Tensors for Element 2 of List Are Equal : False
>>> Trainable Tensors for Element 3 of List Are Equal : False
>>> Trainable Tensors for Element 4 of List Are Equal : False
>>> Trainable Tensors for Element 5 of List Are Equal : False
>>> Trainable Tensors for Element 6 of List Are Equal : False
>>> End Trainable Weights Comparison
```

Comment: I am more curious about the thought that gave you the impression that it might not be valid?

Comment: Abhishek,
I think I just panicked, to be honest. My intuition is that my method IS valid. When I first drafted this question, I used the `.copy` method of the `trainable_weights` list. This of course is a shallow copy of the list, so any changes to the list in the training loop would be reflected in the list that I assigned before the loop. When I changed the copy to `deepcopy`, I think I solved my problem. --Jared

Comment: Yes, your method is correct. It just made me curious. Well I guess it's a tendency that sometimes when our  code runs and give the correct results without much effort then we think there is a bug.

Comment: Abhishek: Thank you for verifying. I appreciate your input, and you are exactly right that my concern came from the code running without much effort! Have a good day! -- Jared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing from the comments and adding some more information, for the benefit of the community:

The method followed in the above code, i.e., comparing **`deepcopy(model.trainable_weights)`** before `Training` with **`model.trainable_weights`**, after the `Model` is Trained using `Custom Training Loop`, is **the Right Approach**.

In addition to that, if we **don't want the Model to be Trained**, we can **Freeze** all the `Layers` of the `Model` using the code,
**`model.trainable = false`**.

Comment: A faster approach is to use hash() function for comparison instead of deepcopy()